# int v = n; is this atomic in gcc?

Tags: gcc, thread-safety, atomic

Here's an example of [atomic counter](http://golubenco.org/2007/06/14/atomic-operations/)
But I think it is unsafe.

Codes:
volatile int i;

```
int get_value()
{
   return i;
}

int set_value(int x)
{
   i = x;
}
```

I know about the [gcc atomic builtin](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html), but I cannot find the atomic set value operation.

In my code, I think to get a value safely in this way, is it necessary ?

```
inline uint64_t get_value()
{
    return __sync_fetch_and_add(&m_value, 0L);
}
```

And I don't how to set a value atomic.

Comment: Would you please show me an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you call atomic exactly.  If you mean that get() will always return a value passed to set_value, then the answer is yes on virtually all modern architectures.

Example: If thread 1, calls set_value 10 times with values from 1 to 10, and you have thread 2 printing the return value of get_value, you'll see only values from 1 to 10.  What values depends on many things, you could get 10 times "10" or 10 times "1", but no 11

__sync_fetch_and_add works as well but makes much more guarantee on things like memory ordering but is much more expensive.

Comment: but, if don't use __sync_fetch_and_add to return the value, there's an issue of CPU cache (memory visibility)

Comment: Using __sync_fetch_and_add is not related with the cache.  Pretty much every modern architectures has cache coherency built in hardware, it doesn't matter what instructions you're using.  What  __sync_fetch_and_add does is ensuring some form of order in the visibility of other memory locations.  That's what you I said in my answer `it depends what you call atomic exactly`.  If you're doing referencing counting for example, what really matters would be to have a decrement, increment operations that return the old value of the counter and you'd need to __sync_fetch_and_add for that